# Backing up all databases + index creation scripts?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I was trying to backup all my SQL Server databases and came across the following script from [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1070):

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) -- database name  
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) -- path for backup files  
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256) -- filename for backup  
DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20) -- used for file name 

SET @path = 'C:\Backup\'  

SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112) 

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT name 
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')  

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       SET @fileName = @path + @name + '_' + @fileDate + '.BAK'  
       BACKUP DATABASE @name TO DISK = @fileName  

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

This works perfectly fine except that I'm thinking that I'll have to reconstruct all the indexes of the database after I restore it. I wanted to know if it is possible to dump the `CREATE` statements for all the indexes so that I can re-run them in one-go after restoring all these database?

Comment: A database backup does include the indexes.

Comment: That's so relevant, I'll repeat it: when you back up a database, the indexes within that database are included in the backup. At least, that's true for SQL Server.

Comment: Hmm... someone told me I cannot backup indexes! :( But guess I heard it wrong. Thank you for the clarification. Great relief!

Comment: @Legend I think you need to go educate the source. :-)

Comment: It was on SO. I am trying to find the source. I'll post it here when I find it and now I am desperate! There's no way I'd conclude that because I am new to SQL Server :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the regular maintenance backup operation? If not, then it must add a [`WITH COPY_ONLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191495.aspx) clause, otherwise it breaks the backup chain.

As a regular maintenance backup this is rather poor:

- it ignores each database recovery model (may be different)
- it does not do a good job of scheduling full/differential/log backup (ie. uses way too much disk space and causes way too much disaster recovery loss of data)
- it is not error safe, one db error will fail the entire loop
- it does not sanitize the file names generated (eg. a database named `[a:b]` will create an invalid file name and always fail).
- it does not do maintenance of old backups and reclaim disk space from obsolete backups
- it does not allow for things like [backup compression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964719.aspx)
- backup on the same disk as the database is a useless illusion of safety, you'll lose all data anyway on disk loss

But ultimately the fundamental issue is that you're looking at it from the wrong angle. Your goal is not to have a backup plan, but to have a **recovery** plan. Read some more here: [Importance of testing your disaster recovery plan](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Importance-of-testing-your-disaster-recovery-plan.aspx). And btw, you need a recovery plan for `master` too.

As for your question about indexes, I don't think you understand how SQL Server backup works at all. Start here: [SQL Server: Recovering from Disasters Using Backups](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee677581.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed list of pointers. I will go through the links. My scenario is this: I will be migrating from account A to account B (on the same machine) but I created these databases with account A. But until I surrender A, I will not know what B is. I am not sure if I can still access these DBs from B because I created them from within A. So what I am trying to do is to prepare a migration plan rather than a precise backup plan. If you think this can be simplified somehow, please let me know. I will still be using the same machine but with a different login.

Comment: Yes, a migration plan is something different from a backup plan. First and foremost: do you have an existing backup plan? This migration plan would ruin it because it would break the backup chain, you have to use `WITH COPY_ONLY`. I recommend you use this option *anyway*, just in case you will later reuse the migration code again on a server that *does* have a maintenance plan. There aslso hot standby alternatives to migration, like log shipping http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187103.aspx or mirroring http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189852.aspx